# Android, should I use a service or just broadcast Receiver?

Tags: android, android-studio, service, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

for context I am creating an android app that will allow users to set multiple alarms that will notify them with notifications in future to do something and I was wondering the best way to achieve this.

Currently I'm going to use an alarm manager and broadcast receiver to achieve this but I wondered if I should create a service for this or if that was redundant for my intents

Any help appreciated, Cheers.

Comment: What would making a Service give you?  You have to use BroadcastReceivers and AlarmManager (or JobScheduler).  You don't need a Service to post notifications.  So what would it buy you to have a Service and what would it be doing?

Comment: That was the though I had but I wasn't sure this being my first app so I hoped for some confirmation in case i was doing something wrong, Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need of creating your own service class or using intent service, as per your given requirements you can rely on Broadcast receiver and alarm manager to notify a person at specific time. what else you can do to add BOOT_COMPLETED permission in your manifest to wake the receiver after rebooting your phone.

Comment: Thanks that helps a lot!